# Web deploy to Azure from visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, azure-web-app-service, acl, msdeploy

On publishing to Azure, changes are not reflecting. Following is the output I got. I do not understand why does it say 'Task "MSdeploy" skipped'. Please help.

```
 Starting Web deployment task from source: manifest(C:\Users\Gayatri\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\obj\Release\Package\WebApplication1.SourceManifest.xml) to Destination: auto().
2>    Using ID '60782d5c-ed62-4a03-bb62-8719787dc8e8' for connections to the remote server.
2>    Adding ACL's for path (WebApplication18657)
2>    Adding ACL's for path (WebApplication18657)
2>    Using ID 'a2d5f3af-351f-4f3d-bf19-af503f5a0b49' for connections to the remote server.
2>    Adding ACL's for path (WebApplication18657)
2>    Adding ACL's for path (WebApplication18657)
2>    Successfully executed Web deployment task.
2>    Publish Succeeded.
2>    Task "MSdeploy" skipped, due to false condition; ($(UseMsdeployExe)) was evaluated as (False).
2>Done building project "WebApplication1.csproj".
2>Web App was published successfully http://webapplication18657.azurewebsites.net/
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Do you try to check whether the new published files is under your site wwwroot folder (D:\home\site\wwwroot>) via [Kudu Console tool](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console)?

Comment: Yes the published files are updated in root folder on checking with Kudu console.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, it seems that you could not see changes of your web page even if the updates are published to site root folder. Here is my suggestion:

1. restart current Azure web app
2. clear browser cache
3. view the web app and check whether changes are reflecting

Comment: Yes it worked after restarting it a thousand times. Maybe it is an issue with Azure.